# Quickest way to apply a formula to a column which requires the last output

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, lag

I have a dataset for which I am calculating the "Hazard rate" defined by the below formula:

```
if t = 1:
     hr_t  = pd_t

else:
     hr_t = (pd_t * (t - (t-1)) + hr_(t-1) * (t-1)) / t
```

where t stands for time (indicated by Years)

The simplest way to do this would be to iterate over each row in the table. However, this will also be the slowest. Is there an efficient way to calculate the above two formulas based on the condition in a pandas dataframe?

```
#Create the year and PD values
data = {'Year':[1,2,3,4,5],
        'PD': [0.1, 0.23, 0.22, 0.19, 0.10]}
data

#Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

The hazard rate at each time period (t indicated by each row) is calculated using one of the two functions above. As the year increases the hazard rate references the same line but is a function of the year before

Example output:

```
Year    PD    Hazard_rate
1       0.1   0.1
2       0.23  0.165
3       0.22  0.226667
4       0.19  0.2125
5       0.10  0.172
```

The hazard rate for year 2 is calculated in the following way:

```
PD      Year-(Year-Year-1)+hazard_rate_(Year-1) * (Year - 1) / (Year)
0.23 * (2 - (2 - 1)) + 0.1 * (2 - 1) / 2 = 0.165
```

Comment: How does t, HR_, HR_t and PD_t work in the formula, are they columns? Can you provide the full input needed for the function to work please? My suggestion: define a function and use apply. If you could provided the inofrmation requested I can create a sample case for you to see.

Comment: Could you please provide desired output for the given input? Please take a look at how to provide [mcve].

Comment: Please add example of the output required, as the formula is not clear.

Comment: I have provided an example of the output required

Comment: the output is wrong for the year 3: (0.22+(0.165*2))/3 (for t=3) gives 0.18333 no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Create the year and PD values
data = {'Year':[1,2,3,4,5],
        'PD': [0.1, 0.23, 0.22, 0.19, 0.10]}
data

#Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

# initialize the series
df['Hazard_rate'] = 0

# iterate over the data frame rows (you need to loop since subsequent
# calculations are depending on prior ones, pandas.DataFrame.apply() is
# just going to implement a loop under the hood anyway
# ASSUMPTIONS: hr_(t-1) is the hazard rate value for the prior year
#              all other "t" is just the row's Year value
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.Year == 1:
        df.loc[index, 'Hazard_rate'] = row.PD
    else:
        hr = (row.PD * (row.Year - (row.Year - 1)) + df.loc[df.Year == (row.Year-1), 'Hazard_rate'] * (row.Year - 1)) / row.Year
        df.loc[index, 'Hazard_rate'] = hr
```

EDIT: user was getting a bug/error, so this list implementation should work (same assumptions as above).

```
#Create the year and PD values
data = {'Year':[1,2,3,4,5],
        'PD': [0.1, 0.23, 0.22, 0.19, 0.10]}

#Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

hazard_rates = [0] * len(df.index)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.Year == 1:
        hazard_rates[index] = row.PD
    else:
        hr = (row.PD * (row.Year - (row.Year - 1)) + df.loc[df.Year == (row.Year-1), 'Hazard_rate'] * (row.Year - 1)) / row.Year
        hazard_rates[index] = float(hr)

df['Hazard_rates'] = hazard_rates
```

Comment: This answer is going to be correct as soon as I figure out why I'm getting this error

Comment: ---> 13         df.loc[index, 'Hazard_rate'] = hr
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series

Comment: Not sure, looks like a bug? but instead of adding it directly to the df, you can initiate a list of length equals number of rows, add the HR values to the list by index, then just add the entire list as your new series after the loop.

Comment: I still received some errors so I made a couple of changes

    df["hazard_rates"] = 0
    df

    hazard_rates = [0] * len(df.index)
    hazard_rates

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.Year == 1:
            hazard_rates[index] = row.PD
            df['hazard_rates'] = hazard_rates
        else:
            hr = (row.PD * (row.Year - (row.Year - 1)) + df.loc[df.Year == (row.Year-1), 'hazard_rates'] * (row.Year - 1)) / row.Year
            hazard_rates[index] = float(hr)
            df['hazard_rates'] = hazard_rates

Comment: In your proposed edit, you reassign the DataFrame.Series each iteration with the entire list. This is not necessary as you can just populate the list as you go, then assign it to the series once afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you get t and HR since they are not in the df but this works with constants, if they are columns, then just replace the constants in the calculation function with row['t'] and remove the HR and t from the arguments for the function

```
data = {'Year':[1,2,3,4,5], 'PD': [0.1, 0.23, 0.22, 0.19, 0.10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

t=1
HR=1

def calculation(row,t_input,HR_input):
    if t_input == 1:
        return row['PD']
    else:
        return (row['PD'] * (t_input - (t_input-1)) + HR_input(t_input-1) * (t_input-1)) / t_input
df['HR_t'] = df.apply(lambda row: calculation(row,t,HR),axis=1)
df.head()
```

Output:

```
 PD Year HR_t
0 0.10 1 0.10 
1 0.23 2 0.23 
2 0.22 3 0.22 
3 0.19 4 0.19 
4 0.10 5 0.10
```

Comment: t represents time which in this example is indicated by years and HR is the number we are trying to derive using the formulas. I am going to try and adapt your function

Comment: Should pd be the year column? Also you had HR in the formula to calculate HR which is confusing. Don't forget to vote if any solution answers your question

Comment: The PD is the probability of default. The hazard rate is recursive and references the previous year's hazard rate in its calculation of the present year (A bit like vintage analysis)